# Unexpected JPA error:Invalid column name

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, ejb

Using jboss5.1.x, ejb3.0

This was driving me crazy for two day now:

I am trying simple where clauses query and I keep on getting that error:

---

this is what I get with JPSQL query:

```
       String queString ="select s from T04SysParms s WHERE s.key_Name='EXECUTION_TIME'"; 
        Query q = em.createQuery(queString); 
        List<T04SysParms> results = (List<T04SysParms>) q.getResultList();
```

exception I get:

org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: key_Name of: com.mirs.ecms.db2.T04SysParms [select s from com.mirs.ecms.db2.T04SysParms s WHERE s.key_Name='EXECUTION_TIME']

---

this is my mappe class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T04_SYS_PARMS", schema = "ECMS")
public class T04SysParms implements java.io.Serializable
{

// Fields

private String key_Name;
private String value_Name;

// Constructors

/** default constructor */
public T04SysParms()
{
}

/** minimal constructor */
public T04SysParms(String keyName)
{
    this.key_Name = keyName;
}

/** full constructor */
public T04SysParms(String keyName, String valueName)
{
    this.key_Name = keyName;
    this.value_Name = valueName;
}

// Property accessors
@Id
@Column(name = "KEY_NAME", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
public String getKeyName()
{
    return this.key_Name;
}

public void setKeyName(String keyName)
{
    this.key_Name = keyName;
}

@Column(name = "VALUE_NAME", length = 200)
public String getValueName()
{
    return this.value_Name;
}

public void setValueName(String valueName)
{
    this.value_Name = valueName;
}

}
```

The actualy table name in database: T04_SYS_PARMS
the mapped table name is: T04SysParms

any idea?
thanks,
ray.

Comment: you select only `VALUE` from that table (T04_SYS_PARMS), I doubt you can create a full object of `T04SysParms` with a single column. I guess the impl. required at least the identity column to be selected as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VALUE` is a reserved word in the sql standard.  Do you actually have a column named that?  If so, you might need to quote it in the query.  Or better, change it to a more meaningful name.

Based on comments, this was likely not the root problem, though I think it's healthy to avoid reserved words.

You've also been showing queries that get only the VALUE_NAME field, but then you're trying to pull a whole T04SysParms out of the result.

Based on the update including the mappings, a JPQL version of the query:

```
String queString ="select s from T04SysParms WHERE s.keyName='EXECUTION_TIME'";
Query q = em.createQuery(queString);
List<T04SysParms> results = (List<T04SysParms>) q.getResultList();
```

should give you back a list of T04SysParms objects conforming to your needs.

It should be possible to do something similar with the SQL form (adjusting it to get all fields), but to get entities rather than individual fields, JPQL is more appropriate.

Comment: I changed it to "VALUE_NAME" and i still get org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: KEY_NAME of: com.mirs.ecms.db2.T04SysParms [select VALUE_NAME from com.mirs.ecms.db2.T04SysParms SYS WHERE SYS.KEY_NAME ='EXECUTION_TIME']

Comment: This is looking like Hibernate is expecting to see a java property named KEY_NAME in the entity and not finding it.  If you're using JPQL, you need to use the Java property names.

Comment: I did.. and still I get: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: KEY_NAME of: com.mirs.ecms.db2.T04SysParms [select VALUE_NAME from com.mirs.ecms.db2.T04SysParms SYS WHERE SYS.KEY_NAME ='EXECUTION_TIME']    I will edit my question with my mapped class

Comment: Good idea.  Having the mapping will help with making suggestions.

Comment: Sorry i deleted your last comment mistakely, anyway: This is what I got: org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [s.key_Name], unexpected token [s] [select s from com.mirs.ecms.db2.T04SysParms WHERE s.key_Name='EXECUTION_TIME']

Comment: Try changing the query to include s explicitly as an alias: "select s from T04SysParms s WHERE s.keyName='EXECUTION_TIME'".  It shouldn't be needed according to docs, but might conceivably vary with hibernate version.  And this most recent error definitely points at it not being  understood.

Comment: Thats the error now: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: key_Name of: com.mirs.ecms.db2.T04SysParms [select s from com.mirs.ecms.db2.T04SysParms s WHERE s.key_Name='EXECUTION_TIME']

Comment: Did you supply the underscore in s.key_Name or did Hibernate convert it somehow?  Could be a confusion in mapping because you've got key_Name as the field name and getKeyName as the accessor, but with the annotation on the accessor, it should not have the underscore.

Comment: Hibernate should be using the bean conventions, deriving the property `keyName` from the accessor `getKeyName()`.  It might also be worth renaming the field names to match this convention in case you want to move your annotations to the fields.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in one of the column names. Make sure you have both a `VALUE` column and a `KEY_NAME` column. Also take car for potential case-sensitivity.

Btw, I don't see why you need a native query here. Can't you use a JPQL query? Note that in JPQL queries you must refer to classes and fields rather than tables and columns. So it's not `KEY` but probably `key`.

By the way `KEY` is sometimes reserved by databases (like `VALUE` as others suggested). How about this - open some database administrator tool and try to run the query. Only after it works there move it to your code.

Comment: I do have VALUE and KEY_NAME columns, I have confirm that. I have edit my question about the JPQL

Comment: @rayman - I still see `KEY`, which is unlikely a class field name. See my update btw

Comment: I did the sql command straight in the databse editor and it worked fine.